# How can I change the color bootstrap's select tag only arrow or text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think bootstrap's select element's color and option tag's color is always the same.

But I want to change the color individually.

How to do this?

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
.select{
    color:#f00;
}
.select option{
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

but it has no effect on the result.

[image]

Comment: Why use the `.` before the select in CSS?

Comment: It's mistakes. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually get what you wanted. So try this one out.

```
<select>
    <option class="one">1</option>
    <option class="two">2</option>
    <option class="three">3</option>
</select>

select option .one{
  color:#000 !important;
}

select option .two{
  color:black !important;
}

select option .three{
  color:green !important;
}
```

or just remove the `.` on `.select` . It is supposedly to be used in classes.

Comment: it should be like " select option.one " there is no space between option and .one cause they both are same div. right..? :/